# Single Logout (SLO) Okta

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, logout

Has anyone gotten Single Logout to work with Okta as an IdP. I am getting a 403 error when I logout from Salesforce. This is the url I end up at:

../my.salesforce.com/saml/LogoutRequest

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, Salesforce doesn't support SLO and Okta supports SP-initiated SLO only.

Comment: ... hmm https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=slo_about.htm&type=5

Comment: I stand corrected. We are using the developer edition of Salesforce and the SAML settings included a Custom Logout URL field for non-SAML logout but no Single Logout Enabled checkbox, single logout URL or binding. We had not clicked "Enable Multiple SAML Configurations" in Salesforce. Doing this now shows the Single Logout Enabled checkbox etc. I think we were still using a fairly old configuration which pre-dated Salesforce's support for SAML logout.

Comment: Having said that, I couldn't get SAML logout to work with Salesforce and don't see any way to debug it.